# how do you activate or set the default rake?

Tags: ruby, rake, rvm, bundler

I have seen many

```
You have already activated rake 0.9.x, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.x.x
```

errors.

Of course, they can be solved (temporarily or always) by some methods like the following.

```
bundle exec rake
```

The method above works but you always have to type bundle exec.

It can also be solved by

```
bundle update
```

But bundle update also updates your other gems.

Some say it can be solved by

```
gem uninstall unwanted_rake_version
```

Yes, the unwanted rake can be installed but it is still marked as activated thus, still giving the error.

One solution would be to explicitly specify the rake version in your Gemfile but, that is not the question. It is on how to set the default rake version, or activate that specific version in rvm or other types of ruby installations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The newer versions of rake can be activated by supplying an optional first argument, that is the gem version.

`$ rake 0.9.2`

Alternatively, if you have an older version of rake you can update the rake script manually to include this parameter (or specify any specific version you want).

The rake script usually lives in /usr/bin/rake (or ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-#{ruby-name}/rake if using rvm). And dictates the version of them gem to load before parsing paramaters.

It looks like this on my system.

```
$ cat ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/rake

#!/home/tomcat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/ruby
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'rake' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first =~ /^_(.*)_$/ and Gem::Version.correct? $1 then
  version = $1
  ARGV.shift
end

gem 'rake', version
load Gem.bin_path('rake', 'rake', version)
```

The important bit is `gem 'rake', version` changing `version` will force rake to a specific version system/rvm wide.

For more info, Katz' [article](http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/) explains nicely how binaries run under rubygems

Comment: As a side note. Bundle exec is the more 'kosher' strategy. If you modify the rake script, ruby-gems can (and probably will) overwrite it. You may want to reference a copy somewhere safe instead

Comment: I see the syntax of `bin_path` is as: `bin_path(name, exec_name = nil, *requirements)`  but I still don't understand...what is the purpose of `exec_name` ie why isn't the command just `Gem.bin_path('rake', version)`?

Comment: The first argument is the name of the gem, the second argument is the name of the executable within that gem (or the default if nil).

Since three arguments exist, you must specify all of them to also specify the version.

See https://apidock.com/ruby/Gem/bin_path/class

Comment: This doesn't work in my environment. Simply typing `$ rake 13.0.6` (in my case) gives me the answer `rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: You have already activated rake 13.0.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 13.0.6. Prepending 'bundle exec' to your command may solve this.`

Answer (score 6):

When I get that error, its usually a result of working between projects that depend on different versions of rake. An easy fix is

```
gem uninstall rake
```

And then in your project directory (assuming you're working with Bundler) simply

```
bundle
```

Comment: I don't get it. simply `bundle` what? Doesn't it need any arguments?

Answer (score 1):

I always uninstall rake first, command like this:

```
gem uninstall rake -v=version
```

then install another version

```
gem install rake -v=version
```