# Multiple versions of same gems on OSX [and how to get rid of them]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, rubygems

When I run `gem list` from my home directory (not from a project), I get a series of gems I have installed on my Mac.  However, there seem to be a lot of gems with different versions that I know I don´t need, like this:

**LOCAL GEMS**

```
actionpack (4.2.6, 4.2.4, 4.2.2)
actionview (4.2.6, 4.2.4, 4.2.2)
activemodel (4.2.6, 4.2.4, 4.2.2)
activesupport (4.2.6, 4.2.4, 4.2.2)
bigdecimal (1.2.7, default: 1.2.6)
io-console (0.4.6, default: 0.4.3)
json (1.8.3, default: 1.8.1)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0, 2.0.0)
minitest (5.9.0, 5.8.4)
psych (2.0.17, default: 2.0.8)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.0, 1.0.7)
rake (11.1.2, default: 10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.2, default: 4.2.0)
slop (4.3.0, 3.6.0)
uglifier (3.0.0, 2.5.3)
```

There are two (or even three) different versions of the same gem installed.  I would guess that this could be that some gems, like Rake, use an older version as the default.

How can I get rid of these outdated gem versions, and how can I set the newer version (e.g. `bigdecimal`, `io-console`, `rake`, etc.) to be the default version of the gem?

Comment: Are you using Bundler with a `Gemfile` in your project folder?

Comment: Yes, I am using it. however when I run gem list im not inside a project, so I guess [maybe I'm worng?] those are the global gems versions, and not the specific for this project

Comment: The gems all go in the same place whether they are for a project or not. What Bundler does is *select* the right version from those installed (or it can install a "correct" version as defined by your Gemfile).

Comment: Ok, I see... so if I want to use rake 11.1.2 for all my projects from now on  [without having in mind the ones I'd previously made] there should be a way to set rake 11.1.2 as the default version and get rid of 10.4.2, no?

Comment: The easy way is to uninstall all versions of `rake` and then load back in just the one you want.

Comment: I've tried but I got an error which says that tihs version cannot be unninstalled because it's a default gem.

Answer (score 5):

You can remove gems globally from your computer by typing this

```
gem uninstall <gem_name> --version x.x.x
#Removes particular version of the gem

gem cleanup <gem_name>
#will remove all versions except the latest
```

But its not bad to have different versions, unless you think they are really obsolete and will never be used again.

To use a particular version of gem, I think Gemfile.lock is the best way to go. Or else you can refer this one [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665949/how-do-you-activate-or-set-the-default-rake) . It shows a similar problem to yours.

Comment: but if I try to remove rake I get this


`Miguel@MacBook-Pro ~> gem uninstall rake --version 10.4.2
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::InstallError)
    gem "rake" cannot be uninstalled because it is a default gem`

Comment: Are you using rvm?